# PHP postback on submit

Tags: php, forms, submit, postback

I have a question on php postback

My code is :

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["Delete"]))
{  
   echo "DELETE";
}

if(isset($_POST["Modifier"]))
{  
   echo "Modifier";
}

if(!empty($_SESSION["Status"]))
{
    if($_SESSION["Status"] == "u")
    {
        header("Location: Index.php?Action=Acceuil");
    }

    if($_SESSION["Status"] == "a")
    {
        $Connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root") or die(mysql_error());                
        mysql_select_db("tpw34") or die("Nope.");                
        $query = "Select * From Products";
        $result = mysql_query($query);


        While($ligne = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            //Index.php?Action=AdminDeleteProduct&Delete=".$ligne["ProductID"]."
            echo "<form method='POST' Action='#'>";
                echo "<table border='1'>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td colspan='2'><center><img  width='250' height='250' src='".$ligne["Image"]."'/></center></td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<th>Nom du produit :</th>";
                    echo "<td>".$ligne["ProductName"]."</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<th>Prix :</th>";
                    echo "<td>".$ligne["Prix"]."</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<th>Description :</th>";
                    echo "<td>".$ligne["Description"]."</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td colspan='2'h><input type='Submit' value='Delete' name='Delete'/><input type='Submit' value='Modifier' name='Modifier'/></td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "</table>";
                echo "<br>";
            echo "</form>";
        }
    }
}

?>
```

My Question is : I want to get the ProductID of the item ( in the table ) to be in the `$_POST["Delete"]` and `$_POST["Modifier"]` but i dont wanna change the text on the button. I want to keep DELETE and MODIFIER. I have read many things on the web but i dont find the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Include a hidden form value for ProductID.  Then you can retrieve the value in $_POST['ProductID']

```
 echo "<input type=hidden name='ProductID' value='" . $ligne["ProductID"] . "'>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could work with sessions, where you can temporarily save your information.

[Sessions](http://php.net/manual/de/features.sessions.php)

Or like Tim Dearborn suggested, use a hidden input to send it with the next form submit.